# Plot/overlay fundamental data "EPS" on price chart in trading view version 4

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

Does tradingview.com allow

1. fundamental data like "earnings" on the left y axis and "price" data on the right y axis?

Looking to overlay "eps" on a price chart but can't see anything in the [documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/index.html) that allows this. want to recreate the image below

reference picture: https://ibb.co/3B9Dtkd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with:

- The [financial()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_financial) function to get the data.
- The [scale](https://kodify.net/tradingview/indicator-settings/scale-indicator/#specifying-a-tradingview-indicators-price-scale-with-code) parameter
  in the [study()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_study) function

Example code that plots the Basic EPS of the current ticker on the left scale:

```
//@version=4
study("Earnings", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)
eps = financial(syminfo.tickerid, financial_id="EARNINGS_PER_SHARE_BASIC", period="TTM")
plot(eps)
```

This yields the following result on AAPL, showing EPS on the left scale and price on the right scale.

[image: AAPL Basic EPS]

You can read more about it in [Financial Functions and Metrics to Pine](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/built-in-financial-functions-and-metrics-in-pine-17491/).
You can find a list of financial_id's for the `financial()` function in [Help Center](https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000564727)

Comment: Hi! How do you get the older financial info? I'm using the same code but I only get last 2 years. Is it because I may need a pro / pro+ / premium account?? Thanks in advance

Comment: The number of historical bars available differs by subscription plan. Basic:5K, Pro:10K, Pro+:10K, Premium:20K. See [Compare Plans](https://www.tradingview.com/gopro).