# Plotting 2 Pine Script Indicators starting on different positions in the scale

Tags: pine-script

In Pine script for Trading view, I would like to plot 2 indicators on the same window but not overlaid, IE, I would like the rsi to be on the scale from 0 to 100 and say a stochastic to be plotted from 100 to 200.

Could some one help me with this or point me in the direction of some help please as I can't seem to find any info on this or know the correct terminology to search for.

Comment: For examples, see [Plot/overlay fundamental data EPS on price chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684274/plot-overlay-fundamental-data-eps-on-price-chart-in-trading-view-version-4/64685982) and [MFI - scaling pos and neg money flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642574/mfi-scaling-pos-and-neg-money-flow/66642942)

Comment: Great, thank you for the reply, that is a lot of help. : )

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using :

```
offset   = input(100,   title = "Offset of Higher and Lower TF Plot")
middle = 0
middle = 0
OShigh = offset
OSLow  = offset * (-1)
```

and then

```
rsi_up = rsi + OShigh
plot(rsi_up, title = 'RSI', color = #ff0099, linewidth = 2, transp = 25)
```

Seemed to work :)